# How to configure DirectSound's MaxSampleRate above 20000

Tags: c#, .net, directsound

I'm programming small program to output generated sound.

My sound card is capable of a 48000 or even 192000 sample rate.  Its a Realtek ALC883 7.1+2 Channel High Definition Audio, and the specs [can be found here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=28&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=44).

However, DirectSound's MaxSampleRate has a maximum value of 20000?

I know I can get better than the maximum from my sound card, but how do I configure DirectSound to take advantage of this?  When I try the following:

```
DirectSound ds = new DirectSound(DirectSound.GetDevices().First().DriverGuid);
MessageBox.Show(ds.Capabilities
                  .MaxSecondarySampleRate
                  .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

In message box the number displayed is "20000".

Comment: Notice the sweet, smoky subtleties of my edit.  And compare the latest version with the first version.  I think you'll agree there is at least a 4-vote difference between the two.  If you get in this situation again, feel free to ask for help.  That is, after you've tried your best to help yourself!

Comment: I removed my downvote, you owe @Will a pint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your sound card is not the first device in the devices list (for example, a video card with a tv outpout would appear in the list). You should look at the `DeviceInformation.Description` property. Otherwise, maybe a problem with the driver ?

Comment: will check it. Btw. How to get default playback device? I know I can do my own selection list but I want to use the default one selected in windows sound settings.